# Linear Spectral Unmixing in ENVI 5.3

Tags: envi, minimum-noise-transformation

Trying to perform some Linear Spectral Unmixing on a LandSat 7 scene. I have 6 bands, and after MNF-transformation have kept 4 of them.

I want to perform a Vegetation, Impervious surface, Soil (V-I-S) based classification. The end goal is to generate a map, with each pixel showing the percentage of each pixel that is predicted to be impervious. These will be sampled from 3x3 (90x90m) pixel squares that I have randomly distributed throughout the study areas.

Thus far, I've had limited success. My best result has had an R^2 of 0.64, when compared to the ground-truth digitized 90mx90m squares. I've achieved this by using the Scatter Plot function of MNF Band 4 vs. MNF Band 3, and selecting groups of pixels based upon their appearance on a ground truth image. Here's what the scatter plot that resulted in the best R^2 looked like: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-qDNCi6oOLIcUxseG9OYzIyRkk

I've tried using the Spectral Hourglass Wizard, but it stops during the n-D Visualization stage. The error warning I get is: "SVDC: Argument A must be a 2-D matrix: MEANS". When I hit "OK", ENVI aborts.